# python inheritance. count records

Tags: python, django

I don't understand as well as where call this method(records_quantity), please prompt.
Now I receive an error (AttributeError: 'Subject' object has no attribute 'record_set')

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def records_quantity(self):
        return self.record_set.count()

z = Subject()
z.records_quantity()

class Record(models.Model):
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject)
    record_short_description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: necessary to learn quantity of objects of a class Record and to store in a variable records_quantity

Comment: Please make an effort to write proper English.

Comment: You have to call it in a view. Dont call it in the models.py file. Please read the django tutorial

Answer (score 2):

Create a model method, instead of declaring it as an attribute.

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def records_quantity(self):
        return self.record_set.count()
```

Now you can do something like

```
subject.records_quantity()
```

where `subject` is an instance of model `Subject`

If you dont want to access the `records_quantity` with a `()`, use the `@property` decorator

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    @property
    def records_quantity(self):
        return self.record_set.count()
```

So, you can access it as

```
subject.records_quantity
```